# How to hide command line arguments

Tags: vb6, command-line-arguments

We have a structure of calling helper exes and passing them command line arguments to control their execution. Since command line arguments can be seen and hence can be passed by other applications. We want our exes to be called only by us. 
How can we achieve this with minimum change and keep the current structure of passing command line arguments intact?

**Edit 1**

Can the caller be identified? e.g. call helper exe as child and identify parent

Comment: To edit#1: What stops "enemies" from replacing your caller-exe with one of their own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can not hide command line arguments. You may wish to check [How to clear a process command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992786/how-to-clear-a-process-command-line?rq=1) question and see answers and comments there.

If you want to stick with passing command line arguments, Raymond Chen has a very good post on how to do it gracefully: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/11/56043.aspx. Basic idea is to use anonymous shared memory block for storing actual data to be passed between processes, and passing numeric value of the handle to it.

A heavy weight alternative might be to encrypt/decrypt data passed via command line. Or append some generated "secret word" so the callee can validate whether it is called by one of your applications.

I'd suggest that choice of an approach (and associated costs/benefits) depends on the risks: who/why/when is going to manipulate your helper applications?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a hack to clear the command line parameters in memory after the application has started, by [writing to the address returned from `GetCommandLineW()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx), but that won't stop anything reading it in the mean time, or anything that hooks the process creation.

You could try creating shared memory and passing pointers, but this does little more than obscure the data.

The simple fact is that you can not hide data from anything running as the same user and execution level. Whatever effort you can put into hiding it, can be put into unhiding it. Even encryption means the keys and methods will be in memory and can be read. If you want to stop random users trying to run your executables, then don't give them to random users :)

Comment: Writing to the address returned from `GetCommandLineW()` is of little help. Altering this location has no effect on other applications like ProcessExplorer or Win32_Process WMI class. They are still able to read original command line.

Comment: +1 for "The simple fact is that you can not hide data from antyhing running as the same user and execution level."

Comment: @kurniliya Process Explorer does show the modified data if you write to the pointer returned by `GetCommandLineW()` as Raymond says in his article.

Comment: I tested it more carefully with ProcessExplorer. You were right, of course: change string at `GetCommandLineW()` and PE picks it up. Situation I originally considered appears to be an exception, not a rule: run PE; run your executable that alters its command line; check data in PE's tooltip for the process. The tooltip still shows original command line. I guess PE does not, generally, renew info for tooltips until restart or some other event. It's just example of your "anything that hooks the process creation".

Comment: @kurniliya The tooltip value is cached. It's retreived on first display, and updated whenever the process properties window is opened (which shows the changed value)

Answer (score 1):

Your application can use DDE to communicate with each other. For more information see [Make two Visual Basic program exchange data using DDE](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_dde.html) and [How to Use DDE in Visual Basic to Communicate with Other Windows Programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189498)

Comment: We are looking for the solution with minimum change

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the values into variables and extract those variables in your .exes?

Comment: Assuming you mean environment variables, these are just as readable as the command line.