# C++ application: clear commandline arguments?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a C++ application which uses `CCommandLineInfo` to parse command line arguments.

One of these arguments is a password which we encrypt in memory with `CryptProtectMemory` after the application starts.

At that point I want to get rid of the password which is still in plain text available in memory (when I create a memory dump it can be retrieved).

Is there a way to clear the command line arguments? I tried clearing (overwriting with empty strings) `__argv` but the arguments were still visible in the memory dump.

[edit]
I tried clearing the commandline arguments like this, but that didn't work.
The arguments are still in memory.

```
for (int i=0; i<__argc; i++)
    __argv[i] = "----------------------";

TCHAR* cmdLine = GetCommandLine();
SecureZeroMemory(cmdLine, strlen(cmdLine));
```

Comment: Please show your code. If you overwrite a string eg "asdasdasd" with an empty string "" then the original characters are still present in memory of course as you only overwrite the first one

Comment: Yes, _how_ do you overwrite and _what_ do you overwrite? Please show your code if you want answers. Don't describe your code but show it.

Answer (score 3):

There *is* a well-known trick/hack to clear the command line from the process memory (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992953)), but even if you apply it you can still easily fetch the command line from e.g. [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) since it makes a **copy** of it when the process is started. Thus, there is no way to prevent a tool like this from showing the command line.

Having a password as a command line parameter is simply a no-no. The only solution I can think of is to store the password encrypted/hashed (or worst case; unencrypted) in a file and then load that file as a parameter.

Comment: I'm interested in that well-known trick or hack.. I cannot find it.

Comment: I added a link in my answer. I'm not 100% sure this is the exact same code I used back in the days. Will verify as soon as I find my source code.

Comment: Thanks for linking that post. I tried that, but still see the parameters in Task Manager and the parameters are still in the memory dump. My program is 32bit BTW. Any more ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Like I said; nothing prevents `Task Manager` (or any equivalent) from copying the values. Why wouldn't it? Makes no sense *not* to copy the values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid cleaning up `argv` is not enough, as the source of `argv` is still available using `GetCommandLine()`. Ultimately this information is stored in `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` in `Process Environment Block`. C runtime will cache this information to `argv`. Some other library may cache this information too.

You'd better pass your sensitive data with other IPC - shared memory or pipe. Then you need to clean only your memory.

If you still want to locate original command line, here's approximate direction: `NtCurrentTeb()` to get `TEB`, then there would be pointer to `PEB`, and there would be pointer to `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`, which finally contains pointer to command-line.